# Strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, solr, modx, modx-revolution

hopefully this is a quick and easy fix. I'm using Solr to search on my MODX site and am having some troubles with the PHP... I'm quite a noob when it comes to this stuff. Anyways, the error I'm getting is:

```
PHP warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Here's the function:

```
public function sanitize($text) {
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $text = preg_replace('/(\[\[\+.*?\]\])/i', '', $text);
    return $this->modx->stripTags($text);
}
```

I don't think I can change the spot that's generating $text, so I have to change the function somehow to accept an array (of strings, I would assume). Can anyone help me rewrite this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this means that the `$text` passed to your function is an array and not a string. However you can try using [implode function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert an array to a string. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Osama, I'll read up on that and try it out! I have no experience with PHP though so I might need to some help working it into the function above.

Comment: Ugh I can't figure it out... Could you advise me? Here's a paste of the whole section that uses $text
http://apaste.info/lGd

Comment: @MatthewMeredith in createExtract function, can you use var_dump($text); and show me the output?

Comment: I get:

array(1) { [0]=> string(3111)

Then the content of the page that is the first result. Then I get:

array(1) { [0]=> string(3381)

and the content of the next result. I have also added 

$text = is_array($text) ? implode($text) : $text;

To the start of the sanitize function

Comment: The code I added:

$text= is_array($text) ? implode ($text) : $text;

seemed to do the trick for removing that error. I have a new error "PHP warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty" and "PHP warning: Illegal offset type" that I'll have to figure out